# How do I get the ng-model of a select tag to get the initially-selected option?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm pretty new to Angular, so I may be going about this all wrong...

I have a <select> similar to the following:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="myValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues" value="{{myValue}}" ng-selected="myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected(myValue)">{{myValue}}</option>
</select>
```

This mostly works... The dropdown initially renders with the correct option selected, and if I *change* the selected option, then `mySelectedValue` will get the new selection.  However, `mySelectedValue` does NOT get the *initially*-selected option.  `mySelectedValue` is blank until I change the value in the dropdown.

I looked at ng-init, but that seems to get evaluated before `someDynamicArrayOfValues` is set...

Is there a way I can get `mySelectedValue` to receive the value in the initially-selected <option>?

***UPDATE:***
I forgot to mention that I had also tried using ng-options, but haven't had any luck getting that to work in conjunction with determining which option was selected.

I've tried this:

```
<div ng-show="someDynamicArrayOfValues">
    <select ng-model="mySelectedValue" ng-options="arrayValue for arrayValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues" ng-selected="myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected(arrayValue)">
        <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and this:

```
<div ng-show="someDynamicArrayOfValues">
    <select ng-model="mySelectedValue" ng-options="arrayValue for arrayValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues" ng-init="myFunctionForSettingSelectedValue()">
        <option value="">--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

but neither of those work because the select is built (and ng-init and ng-selected both get evaluated) *before* `someDynamicArrayOfValues` has been set and, therefore, before the <select> is even visible.  When using `<option ng-repeat="...">`, the <select> doesn't get built/initialized until *after* `someDynamicArrayOfValues` is set, which is why I had been going that direction.

Is there a way to get the ng-options technique to work while, at the same time, having the select dependent on `someDynamicArrayOfValues` (if ng-options is the better way to go)?

***UPDATE 2***:
Here's a Plunker (modified from ababashka's answer) that is a little closer to what I'm ultimately trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kj4xalhI28i5IU0hGBLL?p=preview.  It's not quite there yet... I'd like it to have each of the 3 dropdowns set with the closest-matching dynamic value once `someDynamicArrayOfValues` is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it will be good it you will use `ng-options` attribute of `select` tag. It's an angular directive which creates options according to Array of options. You can take a look at [select documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

If you use your code - your function `myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected` works twice for every option at initialization and once for every option item when you select some another option.

#### Demo with your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/0IVNLHiw3jpz4zMKcB0P?p=preview

Demo for select you could see at description of `select` directive.

### Update

At first, to see when value is changed - you need to use `ng-change` attribute of `select` tag, like this:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" 
  ng-options="myValue for myValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues"
  ng-change="myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected()">
  <option value="">--</option>
</select>
```

Then, i don't know how does `myFunctionForSettingSelectedValue` look like, but there are 2 variants:

- This function returns some value - then you need to use `ng-init` next way.

`Controller:`

```
  $scope.someInitFunc = function () {
    return 'One';
  };
```

`HTML:`

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" 
      ng-options="myValue for myValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues"
      ng-change="myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected()"
      ng-init="mySelectedValue = someInitFunc()">
      <option value="">--</option>
</select>
```

- You set value of `mySelectedValue` in this function - then you do this.

`Controller:`

```
$scope.someInitFunc = function () {
  $scope.mySelectedValue = 'One';
};
```

`HTML:`

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" 
  ng-options="myValue for myValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues"
  ng-change="myFunctionForDeterminingWhetherValueIsSelected()"
  ng-init="someInitFunc()">
  <option value="">--</option>
</select>
```

I have created an example which implements the first version of using `ng-init`. When new value is selected - it's printed to console.

Also, i moved options to the `options.json` file. So options are initialized just after ajax request was finished. Everything works great.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/pzjxxTnboKJXJYBGcgNb?p=preview

### Update 2

Hello again. I think you don't need to have any `ng-init` according to your requirements. You can just initiate values of your model when http request is finished. Also i don't understand why do you need `ng-change` function in this case.

Here is modified code you need from your plunk where values of `ng-model`s are initiated after options are loaded.

**JavaScript:**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.someStaticArrayOfValues = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  $scope.mySelectedValues = {};
  $http.get('options.json').then(
    function (response) {
      $scope.someDynamicArrayOfValues = response.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.someStaticArrayOfValues.length; ++i) {
        $scope.someDynamicArrayOfValues.some(function (value) {
          if (value.substring(0, $scope.someStaticArrayOfValues[i].length) === $scope.someStaticArrayOfValues[i]) {
            $scope.mySelectedValues[$scope.someStaticArrayOfValues[i]] = value;
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    },
    function (response) {
      console.log('ERROR!');
    }
  );
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <div ng-show="someDynamicArrayOfValues">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="staticValue in someStaticArrayOfValues">
          {{staticValue}} - 
          <select ng-model="mySelectedValues[staticValue]" 
            ng-options="myValue for myValue in someDynamicArrayOfValues">
            <option value="">--</option>
          </select>
          <h2>{{mySelectedValues[staticValue]}}</h2>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9Q1MH0esGE1SIJa0m2NV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I had also tried using ng-options, with no luck...  I updated my original question with that info.

Comment: @Troy: I updated my answer, so you can take a look at demo with `ng-options` and `ng-init`

Comment: @Troy: By the way, can you please add to your question your `someDynamicArrayOfValues` if this still will not work for you?

Comment: Thanks ababashka.  I updated your plnkr with something similar to what I'm ultimately trying to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kj4xalhI28i5IU0hGBLL?p=preview. I'm still not quite there yet...  I'd like it to initially start with "One - 1" selected for the first dropdown, "Two - 2" selected for the second, etc. after `someDynamicArrayOfValues` is set.

Comment: I believe the answer is to use ng-if in place of ng-show. I posted a separate answer.

Comment: [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) does not recommend using `ng-init` except for aliasing a special `ng-repeat` variable

Comment: @Troy: I updated my answer, so now your values are initiated according to your preferences.

Comment: @NewDev: Yes, i know that. But i just answered to question. Requirements were not clear, so i just explained the way of using `ng-init`. I didn't know what did Troy want to do, but he tried to use `ng-init`. After his updates you can see that he uses it in the `ng-repeat` loop.

Comment: Well, now your last edit is exactly what I said in my answer -> i.e. that ng-model is how you set the initial value.

Comment: Hello, i face one problem in my project i get data in option  form json but when i select option value it's will be store in data base but when i refresh my page my data will lost inside option. but my value store in data base correct. i face problem after reload page to get that value inside option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified plunker that works as intended: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8OSvmrG3u0XjnCU3ah5?p=preview.

The main change was using ng-if in place of ng-show.  This forces angular to recompile/link the html whenever it is rendered:

```
<div ng-if="someDynamicArrayOfValues">
...
</div>
```

Also ng-change, from the original plunker, shouldn't be necessary, and there were a couple of typos fixed.

Comment: That seems a bit flaky and overcomplicated for no reason.

Comment: Which part? Feel free to fork/modify the plunker if you know how it could be done better (while meeting the same needs). I'm new to Angular, so I'm up for learning new points of view.

Comment: The part about `ng-if` and `ng-init`. See my answer below for how it was designed to work

Answer (score 0):

It works a whole lot better when you use ng-options on your select element instead of nesting option with ng-repeat.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Then you are capable of setting the ng-model with ng-init.

Comment: Thanks, I had also tried using ng-options, with no luck...  I updated my original question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the initial value of mySelectedValue in your Controller like so:

```
$scope.mySelectedValue = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created example for your problem in plnkr. 
Visit: plnkr.co/edit/rKyjijGWSL1IKy51b8Tv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the example. It doesn't seem to work, in my case, since ng-init is evaluated before my array of values has been set.  Is there a way to get your example to work when `vm.employees` is initially null and gets set later (and then the dropdowns are shown)?

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it the reverse way. `ng-model` reflects the state of the `<select>` and is two-way bound.

You just need to set your `mySelectedValue` to what you want `<select>` to select first, and no other tricks are required.

So, in the controller, do something like the following:

```
$scope.mySelectedValue = someDynamicArrayOfValues[0];
```

And remove the `ng-selected` and the `<option ng-repeat...>` from `<select>`:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" 
        ng-options="value for value in someDynamicArrayOfValues">
    <option value="">--</option>
</select>
```